# xsl:choose Expression must evaluate to a node-set

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-choose

I am working with `C#` and `XSLT 2.0`. I am having problem with one of templates, it seems to be falling over `<xsl:choose>` statement. Values passed are `Key` - `Value` pairs and all but two values are decimals. Intention is to format decimals with 2 decimal places and `,` on thousands while integers should be without decimal places.

```
<xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="Key='Seller count' || Key='Buyer count'">
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number(Value, '0')"/>
        </td>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number(Value, '#,##0.00')"/>
        </td>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>`
```

is giving me

```
An exception of type 'System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException' occurred in     System.Data.SqlXml.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
```

Which is somewhat surprising as it gets opening and closing `<td> </td>` into both `when` and `otherwise`.

I am assuming that this is something obvious that I am failing to see.

Comment: Can you please post minimal but complete code with your input XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 has the union operator `|` which works on node-sets and the boolean `or` operator which works with boolean values. There is no `||` operator in XSLT, neither in 1.0 nor in 2.0. If you want to write a boolean `or` expression use `<xsl:when test="Key='Seller count' or Key='Buyer count'">` .

Comment: I make this mistake every single time. :) Thanks.